# screenshot using openGL and/or X11

Tags: c, opengl, x11

i am trying to get a screenshot of the screen or a window. I tried using functions from X11
and it works fine. The problem is that getting the pixels from XImage takes a lot of time.
Than i tried to look for some answers on how to do it using openGL. Here's what i've got:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

int width=1200;
int height=800; 
//_____________________________----
 Display *dpy;
  Window root;
  GLint att[] = { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None };
  XVisualInfo *vi;
  GLXContext glc;

  dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

  if ( !dpy ) {
    printf("\n\tcannot connect to X server\n\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  root = DefaultRootWindow(dpy);
  vi = glXChooseVisual(dpy, 0, att);

  if (!vi) {
    printf("\n\tno appropriate visual found\n\n");
    exit(0);
  }

glXMakeCurrent(dpy, root, glc);
  glc = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, NULL, GL_TRUE);


  printf("vendor: %s\n", (const char*)glGetString(GL_VENDOR));

//____________________________________________
glXMakeCurrent(dpy, root, glc);

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); 
GLubyte* pixelBuffer = new GLubyte[sizeof(GLubyte)*width*height*3*3];

glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT); 

GLint ReadBuffer;
glGetIntegerv(GL_READ_BUFFER,&ReadBuffer);
glPixelStorei(GL_READ_BUFFER,GL_RGB);

GLint PackAlignment;
glGetIntegerv(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,&PackAlignment); 
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1);

glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, pixelBuffer);

int i;

for (i=0;i<100;i++) printf("%u\n",((unsigned int *)pixelBuffer)[i]);



return 0;
}
```

when i run the program it returns an error:
  X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
  Major opcode of failed request:  199 ()
  Minor opcode of failed request:  26
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  20

if i comment the line with glXMakeCurrent(dpy, root, glc); before  glc = glXCreateContext(dpy, vi, NULL, GL_TRUE); it returns no erros, but all the pixels are 0.

How should i go about this problem? I am new to openGL and maybe i am missing something important here. Maybe also another way of getting pixels from the screen or specific window exists?

Comment: What makes you thing that using GL will make it faster? It should be the same.

Comment: How much time is it taking? Is there network transmission involved? Are you just viewing stdout in a terminal? Try redirecting to a file and use the `time` command. Printing characters to the terminal uses the same X server that's desperately trying to copy an image and marshall it over a protocol. Heisenberg may apply; your inspection technique may be distorting the very information you seek.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible. You can't use OpenGL to read pixels from window you don't own and which probably don't even use OpenGL. You need to stick to X11.

If you have `XImage` you can get raw pixels from `ximage->data`. Just make sure you are reading it in correct format.

http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/images.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But is it possible to speed it up? I dont think pixels of XImage are linearly presented by the ximage->data. I think pixels are composed of multiple bits scattered across multiple bytes, so you need a lot of bit operations to get pixel values. I am using XGetPixel function and XYPixmap, image = XGetImage( dis, DefaultRootWindow(dis), 0, 0, width, height, AllPlanes, XYPixmap );. Maybe i shodld use different Pixmap, such as ZPixmap? I have to obtain pixel values in some milliseconds, but obtaining all pixels takes sometimes up to a second. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Use XShmGetImage() for a faster method.  For an example see the code in [link](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavdevice/x11grab.c)

Comment: `XYPixmap` is a very bad format. What you want is `ZPixmap`, in which the pixels are linearly presented by the `ximage->data` buffer, as you say. You can use `xcb_image_get()`, but I'm using `xcb_image_shm_get()` and I can get all `1920 * 1080` pixels at about 600 fps (ie. less than 2 ms) (`xcb_image_get()` gives me 200 fps)

Answer (score 4):

You can use XShmGetImage, but you have to query the extensions of the X11 server first, to make sure MIT-SHM extension is available.  You also need to know how to setup and use a shared memory segment for this.

Querying the Extension:

http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavdevice/x11grab.c#l224

Getting the image:

http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=libavdevice/x11grab.c#l537

Answer (score 0):

The following runs once at 140 fps on my platform. `xcb_image_get()` (called with `XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP`) will store all pixels in `ximg->data`, pixel by pixel. On my platform, each pixel is 32 bits, each channel is 8 bits, and there's 3 channels (to 8 bits per pixel are unused).

```
/*
gcc ss.c -o ss -lxcb -lxcb-image && ./ss
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <xcb/xcb_image.h>

xcb_screen_t* xcb_get_screen(xcb_connection_t* connection){
  const xcb_setup_t* setup = xcb_get_setup(connection);  // I think we don't need to free/destroy this!
  return xcb_setup_roots_iterator(setup).data;
}

void xcb_image_print(xcb_image_t* ximg){
  printf("xcb_image_print()  Printing a (%u,%u) `xcb_image_t` of %u bytes\n\n", ximg->height, ximg->width, ximg->size);
  for(int i=0; i < ximg->size; i += 4){
    printf(" ");
    printf("%02x", ximg->data[i+3]);
    printf("%02x", ximg->data[i+2]);
    printf("%02x", ximg->data[i+1]);
    printf("%02x", ximg->data[i+0]);
  }
  puts("\n");
}

int main(){
  // Connect to the X server
  xcb_connection_t* connection = xcb_connect(NULL, NULL);
  xcb_screen_t* screen         = xcb_get_screen(connection);

  // Get pixels!
  xcb_image_t* ximg = xcb_image_get(connection, screen->root, 0, 0, screen->width_in_pixels, screen->height_in_pixels, 0xffffffff, XCB_IMAGE_FORMAT_Z_PIXMAP);
  // ... Now all pixels are in ximg->data!

  xcb_image_print(ximg);

  // Clean-up
  xcb_image_destroy(ximg);
  xcb_disconnect(connection);
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you know why the image size is not 1024*768*3? (3 because RGB) Output: xcb_image_print()  Printing a (1024,768) `xcb_image_t` of 1572864 bytes, depth: 16, bpp: 16

Comment: I think it's always `1024 * 768 * 4`, because each pixel is padded to occupy exactly 4 bytes. So, each pixel has 3 channels (because RGB), but it occupies 4 bytes (so one byte is always zero). I think that's how it goes, although it probably depends on your graphics driver...